# Creating a structured array with mixed data types, but cannot create boolean type

Tags: python, structured-array

So I'm trying to make the 4th column in this one-dimensional array of the boolean data type. I've read that either '?' or 'b' are supposed to work, but neither do. The error I keep getting is shown below after the code I'm using:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([(1, 2., 'Hello', True), dtype=[('int', 'i4'),('float', 'f4'), ('string', 'S10'),('bool','?')])

x[0][3] != x[0][3]
print(x[0][3])
```

```
  File "main.py", line 3
    x = np.array([(1, 2., 'Hello', True), dtype=[('int', 'i4'),('float', 'f4'), ('string', 'S1'),('bool','?')])
                                                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You are missing a `]` after `True)`

Comment: ah! @Wombatz, you beat me by seconds

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a `]` in `x = np.array([(1, 2., 'Hello', True), dtype=[('int', 'i4'),('float', 'f4'), ('string', 'S1'),('bool','?')])`

It should be `x = np.array([(1, 2., 'Hello', True)], dtype=[('int', 'i4'),('float', 'f4'), ('string', 'S1'),('bool','?')])`